# touchBegan in Swift Error

Tags: xcode, swift, touchesbegan

I'm trying to overload the touchesBegan function in Swift but I got a strange error that causes XCode to crash.

I think the problem is at line "`for touch: AnyObject in touches {`" but I used it in other classes and it worked very well.

This is my code :

```
import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene {

    let touchButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Touch")
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView!) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xD64541)
        self.touchButton.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
        let touchButtonWidth = self.touchButton.size.width
        let touchButtonHeight = self.touchButton.size.height
        self.touchButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(self.touchButton)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.touchButton {
                println("button")
            }
            else {
                println("ext")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check `touches` for nil before iterate through it (works for me):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    if let tchs = touches {
        for touch: AnyObject in tchs {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.touchButton {
                println("button")
            }
            else {
                println("ext")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It Works ! Acutally i don't really understand why it didn't work with my method. thank you !